# How can i add ReCaptcha-v2 in react native form?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, recaptcha

1.Webview

On using Webview is there a way to show the picture popup in modal and Recaptcha checkbox alongside the form fields???

2.Without Webview

Also are there any other ways for implementing Recaptcha without using webview?

3.SafetyNet

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safetynet-client   Can ve use SafetyNet to implement Recaptcha in android?

Answer (score 2):

There's already an `npm package` for react-native which implements the `ReCaptacha-v2` functionality in your app, it has a direct dependency to `react-native-modal` and `react-native-webview` though. And, here it is

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-recaptcha-v2

I don't think that I should explain how it works, as the readme from the `npmjs`, explains well how to use it. Also, if you'd like to customize your recaptcha component, there's another package which you should install, instead of the first one.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha-v2-enhanced

So, to sum up, if you're willing only to add recaptcha to your app, use the 1st package, but, if you're planning to customize the provided recaptcha component, use the 2nd package. And don't forget, both these package have a direct dependency to `react-native-modal` and `react-native-webview`